# Getting authentication errors connecting with Microsoft's Spark ODBC driver

Tags: authentication, cassandra

We have a C# console application that reaches out to an Apache Cassandra-based system to get certain data from it. Every now and then (maybe 1-5 times per day), we see the error below occur:

```
An error occurred getting Data. System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): 
ERROR [28000] [Microsoft][ThriftExtension] (2) Error occured during authentication. 
ERROR [28000] [Microsoft][ThriftExtension] (2) Error occured during authentication. 
    at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode) 
    at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionOpen..ctor(OdbcConnection outerConnection, 
     OdbcConnectionString connectionOptions) 
    at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, 
     DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) 
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, 
     DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) 
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection
     (DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, 
     DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) 
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, 
     DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) 
    at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection
     (DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) 
    at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open() 
    at MyProject.Models.DataCollector.ConnectToDB() 
    at MyProject.Models.DataCollector.CollectData()
```

We have 3 environments that this data is retrieved for (dev, test and prod). When the error happens, it most often happens for all 3 environments. This gives me the impression that there may be some sort of connection limit that we're hitting. The vendor for this system recommended that we use Microsoft's Spark ODBC driver for this. Here is what the connection string for the Cassandra DB looks like:

```
@"Driver=Microsoft Spark ODBC Driver;Host=mydb.myorg.com;Port=[portnum];Schema=prodDB;UID=MYUSER;PWD=**********;AuthMech=3;ThriftTransport=1;SSL=1;TwoWaySSL=0;UseSystemTrustStore=0;SparkServerType=3;AllowSelfSignedServerCert=1;CAIssuedCertNamesMismatch=1;TrustedCerts=C:\mypath\mycert.pem;"
```

Are there any settings in this connection string that we should try adjusting, or are there any settings that we should verify within the Cassandra instance? If not, what could be the cause of these authentication errors?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Microsoft's ODBC driver but it looks like it's using the legacy Thrift protocol.

Thrift was deprecated in Cassandra about 8 years ago, replaced by CQL all the way back to 2011 ([CASSANDRA-1703](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-1703)). Drivers based on the Thrift API were retired including Nate McCall's [Hector](https://github.com/hector-client/hector) in 2015 and Netflix's [Astyanax](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax) in 2016.

Cassandra 2.2 stopped using Thrift in 2015 ([CASSANDRA-8358](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8358), [CASSANDRA-9319](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9319)) and Cassandra 4.0 completely removed Thrift in 2016 ([CASSANDRA-11115](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11115)).

You would be very hard-pressed to find community help since Thrift hasn't been supported for years. Your best bet is to contact Microsoft directly to get support for their driver. Cheers!